# Is there a way to sum together lists of data frames within a larger list?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, data-structures, bioinformatics

I have a large list (`z`) containing 3 lists of 10 data frames. I would like to collapse this object into a list of 3 data frames where each data frame is the sum of the 10 prior data frames (think matrix addition). Here is what I am working with, keep in mind that these are fake numbers, as the real data are read in from hundreds of *.csv files

```
x = rep(1,100)
x = matrix(x,10,10)
x = as.data.frame(x)
y = list(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x)
z = list(y,y,y)
```

The desired end product would look like this:

```
x1 = rep(10,100)
x1 = matrix(x,10,10)
y1 = list(x1,x1,x1)
```

I keep trying stuff along the lines of:

```
z1 = c()
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:10){
    z1[[i]] = sum(z[[i]][[j]])
  }
  }
```

However, this does not yield the desired output. I have also messed around with some of the the `apply` functions, but to no avail

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` to sum the corresponding i, j elements in the `list` and collapse it to a single dataset

```
lapply(z, function(x) Reduce(`+`, x))
```

If we want to remove the last column which is not numeric

```
lapply(z, function(x) Reduce(`+`, lapply(x, function(y) y[-ncol(y)])))
```

Or it can be looped over the  sequence of `list`

```
lapply(seq_along(z), function(i) Reduce(`+`, lapply(seq_along(z[[i]]), 
          function(j) z[[i]][[j]][-ncol(z[[i]][[j]])])))
```

---

If we want to use `sum`, the `data.frame`s inside the `list` can be converted to an `array`, loop over the `array` with `apply`, specify the `MARGIN` and do the `sum`.  In this option, there is also possiblity to take care of `NA` elements with `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`

```
lapply(z, function(x) apply(array(unlist(x), c(10, 10, 10)),
        1:2, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or make it more efficient by looping only on one dimension and use `colSums`

```
lapply(z, function(x) apply(array(unlist(x), c(10, 10, 10)), 1, colSums, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
z1 <- replicate(length(z), matrix(0, 10, 10), simplify = FALSE)
for(i in seq_along(z)) for(j in seq_along(z[[1]])) z1[[i]] <- z1[[i]] + z[[i]][[j]]
```

Comment: How would I notate x as an index of z? At the moment, I access the data frames (x) like this z[[y]][[x]]

Comment: @eabrown2378. Are you talking about the `lapply` (first method).  In the `for` loop, we are using `[[` for subsetting with index (`z[[i]][[j]]`)

Comment: Yes, the first method. Additionally, the last column of each data frame is a character vector. Is there a quick fix for removing the last column of each frame?

Comment: @eabrown2378 I updated for removing the last column

Comment: @eabrown2378. For the first method, we are looping over the elements of each `list` instead of index.  If. you need to the same as in `for` loop, then you have to do. `lapply(seq_along(z), function(i) lapply(seq_along(z[[i]]), function(j) z[[i]][[j]]))`, but this is unnecessary

Comment: My reoccurring issue is that I don't have objects that correspond to x & y in this example, only z. With that in mind, what could I use for x & y in the first example, where y is broadly representative of the lists containing dataframes, and x is broadly representative of the data frames. In my actual data, the data frames are not identical (Edit: you already addressed this, thanks!)

Comment: @eabrown2378 Not clear.  Did you meant that my edit solved the issue

Comment: Getting closer, what code could I use in conjunction with `lapply(seq_along(z), function(i) lapply(seq_along(z[[i]]), function(j) z[[i]][[j]]))` to remove the character columns and sum the data frames within each of the large list elements

Comment: @eabrown2378 Please tell me why `lapply(z, function(x) Reduce(`+`, lapply(x, function(y) y[-ncol(y)])))` is not working for you?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for being patient with me, I'll accept your answer

Comment: and by 'it' I mean `lapply(z, function(x) Reduce(+, lapply(x, function(y) y[-ncol(y)])))`

Comment: @eabrown2378 Thanks, I also added the index based approach for your reference